# Howto set custom values on a per form basis in ext:form in TYPO3

Tags: typo3, typo3-11.x

I would like to set custom values for a form by extending the FlexForm configuration of the form plugin.

My question is, how to get the value from the FlexForm into the form. Is there something similar to the finishers, where it is possible to set a variable which is used in the form configuration with the curly braces later on (`{finisher.myVar}`).

This following codes shows, how I extend the FlexForm of the form framework:

ext_localconf.php:

```
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']
    ['SC_OPTIONS']
    [\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Configuration\FlexForm\FlexFormTools::class]
    ['flexParsing']
    [] = \Vendor\Extension\Hooks\ExtendFlexForm::class;
```

Classes/Hooks/ExtendFlexForm.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Extension\Hooks;

use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Core\Environment;
use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility;

class ExtendFlexForm
{
    /**
     * @param array $dataStructure
     * @param array $identifier
     * @return array
     */
    public function parseDataStructureByIdentifierPostProcess(array $dataStructure, array $identifier): array
    {
        if (
            // *** ext:form ***
            // ****************
            $identifier['type'] === 'tca'
            && $identifier['tableName'] === 'tt_content'
            && $identifier['dataStructureKey'] === '*,form_formframework'
        ) {
            // Extend main settings
            // Merging the settings into original settings is needed, in order to use 'displayCond' in flexform
            $content = $this->getFileContent('FormFramework');

            if ($content) {
                $xmlArr = GeneralUtility::xml2array($content);
                $dataStructure['sheets']['sDEF']['ROOT']['el'] = array_merge($dataStructure['sheets']['sDEF']['ROOT']['el'], $xmlArr['ROOT']['el']);
            }
        }

        return $dataStructure;
    }

    /**
     * Add new elements to flexform
     *
     * @param string $fileName
     * @param array $dataStructure
     */
    protected function addDataStructur(string $fileName, array &$dataStructure)
    {
        $content = $this->getFileContent($fileName);
        if ($content) {
            $dataStructure['sheets']['extraEntry'] = GeneralUtility::xml2array($content);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Get content of file
     *
     * @param string $fileName
     * @return false|string
     */
    protected function getFileContent(string $fileName)
    {
        $file = Environment::getPublicPath() . '/typo3conf/ext/extension/Configuration/FlexForms/' . $fileName . '.xml';
        return file_get_contents($file);
    }
}
```

Configuration/FlexForms/FormFramework

```
<extra>
    <ROOT>
        <TCEforms>
            <sheetTitle>Form values</sheetTitle>
        </TCEforms>
        <type>array</type>
        <el>
            <settings.myVariable>
                <TCEforms>
                    <!-- show only, if form is selected -->
                    <displayCond>FIELD:settings.persistenceIdentifier:=:EXT:extension/Resources/Private/FormFramework/Forms/MyForm.form.yaml</displayCond>
                    <label>This is myVar</label>
                    <config>
                        <type>input</type>
                        <size>40</size>
                        <eval>required</eval>
                    </config>
                </TCEforms>
            </settings.myVariable>
        </el>
    </ROOT>
</extra>
```

Now I would like to get the value for `settings.myVariable` into the YAML of my form configuration. But how?